# To check internet connection on after back button is pressed by user.(Alert Box of Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

In My application i checked the internet connection before the application start If the connection is not available then it displayed a alert box with YES and NO button if the user click the No button of alert box then it close the application.

If the user click the Yes button of alert box then I start the an Activity by using the following code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Info");
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Internet connection not available check ur internet connection");
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.exit(0);
        return;
    }
});
```

I want to check the user on the connection or not if the user on the internet connection then it will display the main Activity when the user press the Back Button otherwise Application Exited.

Comment: trying to understand what you have written:
Click on Yes-> take the user to settings
Clcik on NO -> close the application. am i correct?

Comment: just write `finish();` in `NO` button click your application if close...

Answer (score 2):

Use `NetworkInfo` class to check internet connection. When user clicks Back button, call this function.

```
public boolean checkInternet(){
 NetworkInfo network = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (network == null)
     return false;
  if (!network.isConnected())
     return false;
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to override onKeyDown and create custom dialog to do this.

[EDIT 1]

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        // back buton pressed , now you can check connection here

       if(isOnline)
       {
           // go to main activity
       }
       else
       {
          System.exit(0);
       } 

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)     
   context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
       return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: talhakosen Sir I want to also check the connection on by user or not.

Comment: So you should check current internet connection when user click back button, please look at edited answer

Comment: sir  where i write public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) method.

Comment: to your class, like onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if  a user is online by using the following function:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
   if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

You will also need to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

call this method on button click & add internet permission & access network state in menifest.

```
protected boolean checkConnection(Context mContext) {
    final NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (info.isRoaming()) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```